# Flexbox: two divs on top, two on bottom. Can't get it to work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to place two divs next to each other occupying the top half of a flexbox container, and in the same container put two divs next to each other on the bottom.
I've been trying with align-self, flex-wrap, align-content, etc., but all I get is two divs next to each other occupying the left hand top half of the container, and two divs next to each other occupying the right hand bottom half of the container.

The HTML I'm using is :

```
<div class="flexcontainer" style="height: 370px; border:1px solid white; justify-content: flex-start;">
  <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 30%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid red;">
    <select id="nameselect" size="2" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><?php echo implode("\n", $options); ?></select>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 35%; height: 180px; margin: 2px; border: 1px solid green; align-self: flex-start;">
    <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 8%; height: 25px; border: 1px solid tomato; align-self: flex-start;">
    </div>
    <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 92%; height: 25px; border: 1px solid tomato; align-self: flex-start;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 35%; height: 180px; margin: 2px; border: 1px solid blue; align-self: flex-start;">
    <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 8%; height: 25px; border: 1px solid tomato; align-self: flex-start;">
    </div>
    <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 92%; height: 25px; border: 1px solid tomato; align-self: flex-start;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 35%; height: 180px; margin: 2px; border: 1px solid yellow; align-self: flex-end;">
    <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 8%; height: 25px; border: 1px solid tomato; align-self: flex-start;">
    </div>
    <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 92%; height: 25px; border: 1px solid tomato; align-self: flex-start;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 35%; height: 180px; margin: 2px; border: 1px solid grey; align-self: flex-end;">
    <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 8%; height: 25px; border: 1px solid tomato; align-self: flex-start;">
    </div>
    <div class="flexcontainer" style="width: 92%; height: 25px; border: 1px solid tomato; align-self: flex-start;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for class flexcontainer is:

```
.flexcontainer {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The fiddle can be found here:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phloks/fncsob3w/1/)

(One strange thing: in my browser -FF- the green, blue, yellow and grey boxes are within the container (black border). Green and blue next to each other in the top half on the left, yellow and grey next to each other in the bottom half to the right. Also, the two tomato colored boxes are within the green, blue, yellow and grey boxes, but next to each other in the top of the boxes.
I do not understand why in my fiddle the layout is different...)

Is there anyone out there that can help me with this, please ?
I may have been looking at it for too long, and maybe there's something wrong in my html or css, but I don't see it....

Thanks,
Hans

Comment: Can you wrap extra wrapping divs to create rows/columns...it's probably the best option?

Comment: It would also be helpful to simplify your fiddle to remove items that aren't related to the issue **and** extract the inline styles to the CSS area.

Comment: Remove the inline styles please. It's confusing for us.

Comment: Ok, in the train right now. Will adapt tonight. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There were several things that I found while restructuring your code that I think will help you accomplish the desired result.  [See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/es7L8q5z/).

1. Restructure the html to put the green, blue, yellow, and gray divs into a separate container (called #main in the JSFiddle).

   - Putting the green, blue, yellow, and gray divs into a separate container (#main) allows the red (#sidebar) and new light blue (cornflowerblue, #main) divs to be easily aligned next to each other.
   - This allows the `flex-wrap` in #2 to wrap the green, blue, yellow, and gray divs properly.
2. Add `flex-wrap` to the new container (#main).

   - This wraps the yellow and gray divs onto a new line because the green and blue divs fill #main on the first line.
3. Use `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` for easier width management.

   - Using some form of a `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` reset includes border and padding as part of width calculations.  This way fewer or no calculations are needed on your part when setting the width.  You will still need to account for margins.
   - You can learn more about this [here](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

[image]

Note: I adjusted some of the border widths and other css values from your example to make it easier to see what was going on.

Comment: Thanks coderfin ! Exactly what I needed. Will dive into the code to see what you did. Thanks again !